# How to mock the Request.form for only a few values on Controller in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq, request.form

I am new to Nunit and Moq framework and am totally stuck in testing for one of my controller as it fetches some of the values from Request.Form["Something"]. I am able to test for the other part of the controller method using nunit but the code is breaking wherever Request.form values are fetched in the same controller.

Below is the test controller code using nunit and Moq:

```
      [Test]
    public void SaveRequest()
    {
        TestController test = new TestController();

        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model = PopulateRequestModel();
        Mail = model.Mail;
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "https://localhost", ""), new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StringWriter()));
        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(HttpContext.Current, new HttpSessionStateContainer("", new SessionStateItemCollection(), new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 20000, true, HttpCookieMode.UseCookies, SessionStateMode.InProc, false));

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["__RequestVerificationTokenError"] = false;

        var httpContext1 = (new Mock<HttpContextBase>());
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        httpContext1.Setup(c => c.Request.RequestContext.RouteData).Returns(routeData);

        httpContext1.Setup(c => c.Request.Form).Returns(delegate()
        {
            var nv = new NameValueCollection();
            nv.Add("Firstname", "Dave");
            nv.Add("LastName", "Smith");
            nv.Add("Email", "jsmith@host.com");
            nv.Add("Comments", "Comments are here...");
            nv.Add("ReceiveUpdates", "true");
            return nv;
        });


        if (LoggedInEnterpriseId != null)
        {
            ViewResult result = test.SaveRequest(model, mail) as ViewResult;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
    }
```

PopulateRequestModel :

```
        private RequestModel PopulateRequestModel ()
    {
        RequestModel model = new RequestModel ();

        model.Firstname = "Dave";
        model.LastName = "Smith";
        model.Email = "jsmith@host.com";
        model.Comments = "Comments are here...";
        model.ReceiveUpdates = true;


        return model;

    }
```

Below is the actual controller method to be tested :

```
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveRequest(TestModel model, HttpPostedFileBase Mail)
    {

        string Name = Request.Form["Firstname"].ToString();
        model.Mail = Mail;

        //Start Adding Request to DB
        Logger.Write("Start: Adding new request..");
        try
        {
            using (db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                NewRequest newRequest = new NewRequest();

                if (RequestNumber != 0)
                {
                    newRequest.Name = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["Firstname"]);
                    newRequest.LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
                    newRequest.Email = Request.Form["Email"];
                    newRequest.Comments = Request.Form["Comments"];                       
                    newRequest.ReceiveUpdates = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form["ReceiveUpdates"]);               
                }
                else
                {

                    newRequest.Name = model.Firstname;
                    newRequest.LastName = model.LastName;
                    newRequest.Email = model.Email;
                    newRequest.Comments = model.Comments;                       
                    newRequest.ReceiveUpdates = model.ReceiveUpdates;     

                }
                db.NewRequests.Add(newRequest);
                int save = db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

The code is getting blocked wherever request.form is used.

Comment: what does "getting blocked" mean, and why are you using Request.Form at all in your controller? You've got your TestModel object which should contain the values you need (and if it doesn't, you need to change your model). By using Request.Form you're entirely missing the benefits of the Model binder in MVC, which is one of the best bits about it.

Comment: Getting blocked means the code coverage is being blocked. We are using the testmodel object but some of the values are fetched at runtime through request.form. So we are able to handle the "else" part but having issue in the "if" part. How do I give those request.form values through my test method.

Comment: "We are using the testmodel object but some of the values are fetched at runtime"...what do you mean? The model object is bound at runtime too, there's no reason not to include all the values you need in your viewmodel. In MVC there should really never be any good reason to use Request.Form unless you have a very unusual circumstance, which this is not, as far as I can see - it looks like a very ordinary form submission scenario.

Comment: P.S. I still don't know really what you mean by the "code coverage is being blocked"...automated testing is not something I'm familiar with. Is this resulting in some kind of error, or what? Please clarify further.

Comment: @ADyson "code coverage is being blocked" === his unit test is failing

Comment: The answer is still the same, don't use Request and then you don't have to try and mock it. Or better yet move all your logic into a logic layer and test that. IMO testing controllers is mostly a waste of time. Testing should test logic, logic shouldn't be in your controller.

Comment: @Liam well yes I figured that, but failing _how_ would be of interest. I agree with you though, it's more important to test the actual program logic, which should generally be taken out of the controller and into separate classes and methods, which can then be unit tested very easily. Reasons to test a controller though might be to see if the model binding occurs as expected, or any security rules are applied correctly, etc.

Comment: Thanks all but the problem is we are not allowed to change the existing code. All we can do is create test methods but no changes are allowed to make in the controller. Hence,no other option but to find a solution for this. The error I am getting is - An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Moq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'Moq.DefaultValueProvider' threw an exception. which is in the line : var httpContext1 = (new Mock<HttpContextBase>());

Comment: @ADyson : We are able to populate the testmodel object through our test controller. As we can see from line -                                TestModel model = new TestModel();
 model = PopulateRequestModel(); But to be able to populate the request.form values we are using Moq where I am facing issue as I believe I am not able to implement it correctly.

Comment: I have no idea what PopulateRequestModel() actually does though, do I? Also you then add some more fields through the NameValueCollection...I suspect you end up adding the same fields twice to the request - once inside the serialised TestModel and once in the extra values. I say that because based on looking at the real controller, it seems in some arbitrary circumstances to read the values from TestModel sometimes, and from Request.Form other times (based on the value of a variable we can't see from the code) but actually it's the same field names, so really it's reading the same request data

Comment: That's why I was saying the controller code really didn't make any sense, and it seemed ludicrous to read from Request.Form - all the values it reads from Request.Form look like they would already be present in the model class. Shame you can't change that code, because it seems like that's the real problem.

Comment: But...from your testing perspective, you can try not adding the NameValueCollection for a start, since the same values should already be added to the request by serialising the TestModel class, assuming that PopulateRequestModel does what I would expect.

Comment: It's also unclear why the controller accepts `, HttpPostedFileBase Mail` as a separate parameter, when it's clear from the code that TestModel already includes the same field...no sense in sending the file twice, it doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: *we are not allowed to change the existing code* unit testing shouldn't be like this. You can't unit test in isolation to the code base. Often the code is untestable (`static` methods being a prime example) and/or incorrect. The point of unit testing is to make better code, just adding tests to bad code isn't going to make anything better. Tl;Dr if you have the option feedback to whoever did write this code that they've done it wrong and it's making testing very difficult

Comment: @ADyson The code that I am sharing is actually a simplified version of my actual complex code with the values being changed. And also I believe there isn't any possible solution for this problem.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for understanding. We are struggling to get our code coverage increase but cannot because of the way in which the code is written and even worse is that we can't help it. So I believe there is no possible solution for this?